# Docker (Snap) Containers Getting Stopped

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, snap

I've installed Docker using Snap. Recently running containers have been getting stopped on their own. This happens say 2-3 times in the space of ~8-10 hours. I've been trying to find a root cause without much success. Relevant information below. Let me know if I can provide more information to help.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build cd8016b6bc
```

```
$ snap --version
snap    2.51.4
snapd   2.51.4
series  16
ubuntu  18.04
kernel  5.4.0-81-generic
```

Docker `daemon.json`

```
$ cat /var/snap/docker/current/config/daemon.json 
{
  "log-level": "error",
  "storage-driver": "aufs",
  "bip": "172.28.0.1/24"
}
```

```
$ dmesg -T
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:37 2021] aufs aufs_fill_super:918:mount[18200]: no arg
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:37 2021] overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:43 2021] br-6c6facc1a891: port 5(veth4c212a4) entered disabled state
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:43 2021] device veth4c212a4 left promiscuous mode
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:43 2021] br-6c6facc1a891: port 5(veth4c212a4) entered disabled state
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:45 2021] br-6c6facc1a891: port 1(veth1c95aae) entered disabled state
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:45 2021] device veth1c95aae left promiscuous mode
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:45 2021] br-6c6facc1a891: port 1(veth1c95aae) entered disabled state
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:45 2021] br-6c6facc1a891: port 4(veth1dfd80e) entered disabled state
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:45 2021] device veth1dfd80e left promiscuous mode
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:45 2021] br-6c6facc1a891: port 4(veth1dfd80e) entered disabled state
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:46 2021] br-6c6facc1a891: port 2(veth8e48cf4) entered disabled state
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:46 2021] device veth8e48cf4 left promiscuous mode
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:46 2021] br-6c6facc1a891: port 2(veth8e48cf4) entered disabled state
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:46 2021] br-6c6facc1a891: port 3(veth534c1d3) entered disabled state
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:46 2021] device veth534c1d3 left promiscuous mode
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:46 2021] br-6c6facc1a891: port 3(veth534c1d3) entered disabled state
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:47 2021] br-6c6facc1a891: port 6(veth316fdd7) entered disabled state
[Tue Sep 14 20:31:47 2021] device veth316fdd7 left promiscuous mode
```

Note the difference in timestamp between Docker logs, below and `dmesg`, above.
The Docker logs appear to be from previous time I restarted containers using `docker-compose`.

```
$ sudo snap logs docker
2021-09-14T15:01:19Z docker.dockerd[27385]: time="2021-09-14T20:31:19.783211664+05:30" level=error msg="connecting to shim" error="dial unix \x00/containerd-shim/af7c138e4399d3bb8a5615ec05fd1ba90bc7e98391b468067374a020d792906d.sock: connect: connection refused" id=2b9e8a563dad5f61e2ad525c5d590804c33c6cd323d580fe365c170fd5a68a8a namespace=moby
2021-09-14T15:01:19Z docker.dockerd[27385]: time="2021-09-14T20:31:19.860328985+05:30" level=error msg="connecting to shim" error="dial unix \x00/containerd-shim/281fedfbf5b11053d28853b6ad6175009903b338995d5faa0862e8f1ab0e3b10.sock: connect: connection refused" id=43449775462debc8336ab1bc63e2020e8a554ee25db31befa561dc790c76e1ac namespace=moby
2021-09-14T15:01:19Z docker.dockerd[27385]: time="2021-09-14T20:31:19.878788076+05:30" level=error msg="connecting to shim" error="dial unix \x00/containerd-shim/ff2c9cacd1ef1ac083f93e4823f5d0fa4146593f2b6508a098b22270b48507b4.sock: connect: connection refused" id=4d91c4451a011d87b2d21fe7d74e3c4e7ffa20f2df69076f36567b5389597637 namespace=moby
2021-09-14T15:01:19Z docker.dockerd[27385]: time="2021-09-14T20:31:19.906212149+05:30" level=error msg="connecting to shim" error="dial unix \x00/containerd-shim/017a3907df26803a221be66a2a0ac25e43a994d26432cba30f6c81c078ad62fa.sock: connect: connection refused" id=79e0d419a1d82f83dd81898a02fa1161b909ae88c1e46575a1bec894df31a482 namespace=moby
2021-09-14T15:01:19Z docker.dockerd[27385]: time="2021-09-14T20:31:19.919895281+05:30" level=error msg="connecting to shim" error="dial unix \x00/containerd-shim/47e9b56ce80402793038edf72fe64b44a05f659371c212361e47d1463ad269ae.sock: connect: connection refused" id=99aba37c4f1521854130601f19afeb196231a924effba1cfcfb7da90b5703a86 namespace=moby
2021-09-14T15:01:19Z docker.dockerd[27385]: time="2021-09-14T20:31:19.931562562+05:30" level=error msg="connecting to shim" error="dial unix \x00/containerd-shim/58d5711ddbcc9faf6a4d8d7d0433d4254d5069c9e559d61eb1551f80d193a3eb.sock: connect: connection refused" id=a09358b02332b18dfa99b4dc99edf4b1ebac80671c29b91946875a53e1b8bd7e namespace=moby
2021-09-14T15:01:19Z docker.dockerd[27385]: time="2021-09-14T20:31:19.949511272+05:30" level=error msg="connecting to shim" error="dial unix \x00/containerd-shim/67de51fdf40350feb583255a5e703c719745ef9123a8a47dad72df075c12f953.sock: connect: connection refused" id=ee145dfe0eb44fde323a431b191a62aa47ad265c438239f7243c684e10713042 namespace=moby
2021-09-14T15:01:24Z docker.dockerd[27385]: time="2021-09-14T20:31:24.671615174+05:30" level=error msg="Force shutdown daemon"
2021-09-14T15:01:25Z systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
2021-09-14T15:01:37Z systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application docker.dockerd.
```

Comment: snap has ongoing issues managing docker, please try installing the `docker-ce` instead using apt-get

Comment: Thanks @NoamYizraeli. Was hoping to do without that :-(

Comment: yeah sorry for that, noticed this a few time by now, if it helps I'll post it as the answer, waiting for updates

Comment: I hate to agree with Noam, but I do. The docker snap has historically had enough issues I've avoided it completely. Canonical maintains it because Docker doesn't want to. That does mean, though, that you can try asking in the snapcraft forum: https://forum.snapcraft.io/ .

Comment: I've asked the same question in the snapcraft forum. Will wait for updates.

Comment: Progress! See: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/docker-containers-getting-stopped/26624/7